# How can I print a PDF/X Mavericks document?

Tags: pdf, printing

A few iterations ago, Mac OS X had a "Save as PDF-X" option available via the print dialogue, with an associated file at /Library/PDF Services/Save As PDF-X.workflow that handled the magic suff I assume.

My understanding is that the PDF/X format embeds fonts and does other "preflight" stuff to make a document good for printshops to use. Outputting in this format is possible with Illustrator and other Adobe products, but I would produce a printshop-ready PDF/X file using software I already have (LibreOffice, Word, etc.)

In Mac OS X 10.9, this "Save as PDF-X" option is nowhere I can find.

Is there any simple way to create PDF/X format files?

https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=PDF/X

Back in 2010, Philip Regan gave some info about doing it with the then present "Save as PDF-X" feature, but it is no longer part of the print dialogue.
[How can I print a PDF X-1A from a iWork Pages document?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3563/how-can-i-print-a-pdf-x-1a-from-a-iwork-pages-document)

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an Automator print plugin that prints as a PDF-X.

Open Automator.app

Select "**Print Plugin**" at the *Choose a type for your document* screen

Select "**PDF**" from the *Actions* menu

Drag "**Apple Quartz Filter to the PDF Documents**" to the workflow space on the right

When prompted choose if you want to create a copy of the original, add or don't add

In the Apply Quartz Filter to PDF Documents workflow, in the **Filter** dropdown, choose "*Create Generic PDFX-3 Document*".

Choose File-->Save

Name whatever you like (PDFX)

This will add a workflow back that allows for PDFX again. The workflow is saved in your user directory ~/Library/PDF Services/

Comment: To nitpick a bit, it might be a better choice to create a PDF/X1-a document; this is the only PDF/X format which does not leave anything to interpretation.

Comment: @max-wyss, Do you know how to cread a x-1a workflow? Automator seems to only have x-3.

Comment: Sounds like a lack among those Quartz filters. You might do better using Acrobat and the Preflight plug-in and create a Preflight Droplet.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using Automator is that is doesn't easily allow you to bring up a file dialog, so you have to save it to a preset location.

The other problem (worse) is that Apple's "Generic PDF/X-3 document" Filter is pretty hopeless, and does not always produce a compliant document. It also has terrible transparency settings.

A better PDF/X-3 Quartz Filter [can be found here](https://github.com/benwiggy/PDFsuite/blob/master/QuartzFilters/Better%20PDFX-3.qfilter), and a PDF Service that applies the better filter to the outgoing PDF data, before bringing up a save dialog, [can also be found here](https://github.com/benwiggy/PDFsuite/blob/master/PDF_Services/Save%20As%20PDF-X.py).